# Z-Index of child item higher than container DIV

Tags: css, z-index

I have two block elements, a header, and a nav.  The header has a `div` inside of it that overflows above the nav.  I used `z-index` to define those items that way, but now I have `a` items *inside* of the nav that I'd like to be the most prodominent/highest element on the page, so to appear above the header and it's overflowing elements.  Is this possible?

Please see example - http://jsfiddle.net/zAehr/  - I'd like the Nav `a` items to be above the blue `logo` class.

My CSS:

```
#header {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 height:100px;
 width:100%;
 overflow:visible;
 background:#eee;
 z-index:10;
}

.logo {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 height:250px;
 width:250px;
 background:#336699;
 z-index:10;
}

#navbar {
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background:#bbb;
 z-index:9;
}

#navbar a { 
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 padding:10px;
 z-index:100;
 float:left;
}
```

Many thanks SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the `z-index: 9` off of `#navbar`

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/zAehr/1/

Comment: Hm.  That was pretty simple, lol.  Thanks for the response.  For sake of curiosity, though, if one needed to define that container's `z-index` as well... would the same scenario still be possible?

Comment: the container `z-index` will determine the `z-index` for itself and descendants, if you had to have a `z-index` on `#navbar` you could structure your markup different so the links were in a separate container that didn't have a `z-index`

Comment: Awesome to know.  Very appreciated.

Comment: if you want to know more about `z-index` and element stacking in general, lookup "stacking context" (MDN has a good write-up: [The stacking context - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context))